# Bicycle dull noise when pedalling

Tags: mountain-bike

My bike is making this very weird sound. It’s kinda dull I can feel sort of vibration when pedalling. It gets worse going uphill I think. Please check the video to hear it.

https://streamable.com/tg3zkx

Does anyone know what that might be? I’ve tried tightening everywhere, greasing it up but it is getting kinda worse.

Thanks a lot!

More vids: now it’s making a complete difference sound.
https://streamable.com/c2htm2

Comment: +1 simply for having shoes that *exactly* match the bike

Comment: From the video it's impossible to tell with any certainty.  Kinda sounds like chain noise (not properly adjusted or rubbing the front derailer), but it could be several other things, including something loose/wonky with the bottom bracket or crank arms.  And I wouldn't discount brake noise.

Comment: I feel bad for you. That would drive me bananas and I would likely work straight through the night till it was gone or I fell out on the shop floor. My investigation route for that sort of noise  would-be pedal, bottom bracket, crank arm ,(re-torque the arms' fixing bolts or left arm pinch bolts depending on system). The seat and seat post next to rule out.

Comment: Hi guys! 

Recorded a new vid. Strange as the sound is slightly different from the first one. I’ve noticed it gets worse during longer rides. 

https://streamable.com/ulsmmi
https://streamable.com/c2htm2

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was that you are getting some rubbing of the chain on the front derailleur. Rubbing would only occur when in highest or lowest gears though, and you don't mention that. You can check for this by holding the rear wheel off the ground, pedaling manually and inspecting the chain where it passes through the front derailleur, if you want to rule this out.

Unfortunately I think that a problem with the bottom bracket bearings (bearings that the crank axle runs through) is more likely, especially as you say you can feel vibration through you feet. To check for this manually turn crank arms on either side of the bike, you may feel some resistance, roughness or clicking as the crank turns. (If you can get the chain out of the derailleur cage and off the chainrings it makes it easier to feel this.) You can also try to rock the crank in the frame, there should be hardly any play between the crank and the frame.

From the video I can see you have a cartridge type bottom bracket. The cranks on either side are attached via a square or splined taper on the end of the axle. These cannot be adjusted or repaired and simply have to be replaced. They are not particularly expensive or difficult to install, but do require some special tools (a crank puller, BB removal/installation tool and if you're doing things right, a torque wrench).

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xUtOeFJJycg) shows what's involved and the tools needed.

Comment: Hi guys! Recorded a new vid. Strange as the sound is slightly different from the first one. I’ve noticed it gets worse during longer rides. 

https://streamable.com/c2htm2
streamable.com/ulsmmi